# Why is Array.fill() not available whit ES6 target

Tags: typescript

I'm migrating some js code to typescript and I'm facing some issues with `Array.fill`.

I used to have this code

```
Array(4).fill(0).map()
```

and I changed it to

```
Array<number>(4).fill(0).map()
```

but I get this error

```
Error:(22, 49) TS2339:Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'number[]'.
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.js"
  ]
}
```

I already check this issue [#9436](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9436).

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
let arr:Array<Number>=new Array(8);
arr.fill(0);
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: I doubt if you want `<Number`> that means something different.

Comment: At least I not longer have the error. But when I try to run `arr.map` I get `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. I will try to fix it by my own.

Comment: if u want to map ,here is an example : 
`let arr:Array<Number>=new Array(4);
  arr.fill(4);
        //[4,4,4,4]
        arr=arr.map(Math.sqrt);
        //[2,2,2,2]`